# How do I change the MTU for only localhost connections on a Red Hat box?

Tags: mtu

I want to change the MTU value for only the connections that are going between localhost / 127.0.0.1 on a Red Hat box.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ifconfig

```
# ifconfig lo mtu 16436
```

You can make the change more permanent by adding to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo:

```
MTU=16436
```